# PHP Email isn't working - Not receiving email

Tags: php, html, email

**Question**

On the website when I press submit for the email, It now does everything Correctly but I do not receive the email, someone please help?

**PHP**

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST ['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST ['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $first_name . $last_name;

$to = "Relentile@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Message";

print_r($_POST);

mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your Message has been sent";

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="contact.php" name="contact_form" method="post">
   <p>
   First name:
   <input name="first_name" type="text"/>
   </p>

   <p>
   Last name:
   <input name="last_name" type="text"/>
   </p>

   <p>
   <br>
   E-Mail:
   <input name="email" type="text"/>
   </p>  
   <br>

   <p>Type your enquiry</p>
   <p><textarea name"message"></textarea></p>

   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
   </p>

   </form>
```

**Old Error Message + data it was sending (2nd Image)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `From:` header should contain an address, not a name.

Comment: Missing semi-colon

Comment: Why do you echo that the message has been sent without checking the return value of `mail()`?

Comment: The missing semicolon is on the line that assigns to `$subject`.

Comment: Fixed the Semi-colon, still receiving the same issue @Musa

Comment: Codes been Updated

Comment: use `mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers,  "From:" . $first_name . $last_name);` comma between $headers and "From:

Comment: Thanks @TamilSelvanC , I am now recieving a version of the text, about to upload pic in original post

Answer (score 0):

Set from method `post` as below.

```
 <form action="contact.php" name="contact_form" method="post">
```

In address bar your data is sending through by default `get` method.But you are using `$_POST[]` in php file.So you are not getting values.

Also in `contact.php` use `$headers` as below:

```
$headers = "From:" . $first_name . $last_name;
```

And

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

also semicolon at end of `$subject` variable.

```
$subject = "New Message";
```

and do following....

```
$first_name = test_input($_POST ['first_name']);
$last_name = test_input($_POST ['last_name']);
$email = test_input($_POST['email']);
$message = test_input($_POST['message']);


    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
```

Where

1.Strip unnecessary characters (extra space, tab, newline) from the user input data (with the PHP trim() function)

2.Remove backslashes () from the user input data (with the PHP stripslashes() function)

Comment: Thank you, I am still receiving the same error. For the mail part is this cod correct?

mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers "From:" . $first_name . $last_name);

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);`  are you getting values

Comment: It doesn't look to have any values, just a 500 Gate Way error still

Comment: Okay, so now I am not getting any errors, but I am not receiving the email

Comment: so what is your actual error?

Comment: It is not giving me an error any more, only appears with the text showing in the second image after pressing submit. Though it looks to have no error, I am not receiving any email

Comment: try once with removing `$headers`.

Comment: for seeting headers see more here...http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: i hope it will work nicely.

Comment: Still having no luck, have I done the right approach?

Comment: please read above link once.

Comment: I have read through and I don't see what differs from my code and headers. It did mention that though it may be working it doesn't mean the message is sent and received. Could this be what's wrong with my setup?

Comment: `mail($to, $subject, $message)` try using other values...

Comment: like this..  mail("Relentile@gmail.com","My subject","Hello");

Comment: `Relentile@gmail.com` and check mail inbox.

Comment: I received the message when doing that, but when making it

Comment: I received the message when doing mail("Relentile@gmail.com","My subject","Hello"); , but when making it mail ("Relentile@gmail.com", $subject, $message); Nothing is received

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp see here and find your problem......which may be due to extra spaces..

Comment: `test_input()` is a function. for getting more accurate and efficient form values.

Comment: I'm still having no luck, could this be an issue with godaddy domains?

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: " . $email;

$to = "relentile@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Message";

print_r($_POST);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Your Message has been sent";
```

It should now work.
The headers must be in proper format (spacing).
"From" header contains sender's e-mail address.
When accessing an array in PHP, do not use spaces: wrong = $array ["blah"], good =  $array["blah"]. The same applies for functions.

Comment: I'm still having no luck, could this be an issue with godaddy?